# Dividir fila entre un escalar en Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

¿Alguien puede explicarme esto?¿es un bug?

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> a[0]/7
array([0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857])
>>> a[0] = a[0]/7
>>> a[0]
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

¿Como puedo dividir una fila entre un escalar?

Comment: Si no especificas el tipo de dato que va a almacenar el arreglo, entonces utilizará el menor tipo de dato que se ajuste a lo que declaras. En este caso `int`. Como declaraste un arreglo de enteros y realizas una división y la guardarás en un arreglo entero, el resultado es parseado a entero. En el caso en que no guardas el resultado en ningún lado, y solo lo imprimes, el resultado toma su forma más general.

Comment: Pero me parece raro que sea al acceder a la fila, si lo hago con todo el array funciona perfectamente
`>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])`
`>>> a/7`
`array([[0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857],
       [0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.        , 1.14285714]])`
`>>> a = a/7`
`>>> a`
`array([[0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857],
       [0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.        , 1.14285714]])`

Comment: Si lo haces "con todo el array" en realidad estás guardando un nuevo array en la variable. Es decir, estás cambiando el tipo de dato de la variable. Eso no es más que consecuencias del tipado dinámico de python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no estoy seguro de porque se genera este comportamiento, pero si haces lo siguiente se logra el comportamiento que buscas.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],dtype=float)
a[0]=a[0]/7
a[0]
```

Comment: Ese comportamiento se genera debido a lo explicado por Jaime Menéndez en el primer comentario a la pregunta.